# DJI Drone keeps hovering at height of 1-2m, when (low battery/ serious low battery) hits and it starts retracting home automatically

Tags: ios, dji-sdk

**- Description of the issue:** :When drone is flying in low battery case and start to return home by itself, it stops at the height of 1-2m and never lands, user has to take control of remote control and land it. We don't get any callback

**- Steps to reproduce the bug** Keep on flying and when the drone hits Serious low battery or sometimes in Low battery case it will start retracting home

**- DJI iOS SDK** :iOS SDK 4.4

**- DJI Product** :Mavic Pro

**- iOS system version** :iOS version >11.0

**- iOS device** :iPad mini 2, iPad Air

**- Xcode version** :9.2

**Extra info:** Some times drone keeps on hovering even in normal return home state, we don't get any callback saying can't land or error.

Answer (score 0):

At this time I think you will have to roll your own solution. The same behavior exists with the DJI android mobile sdk. I think the DJI firmware thinks the landing site is not 'safe/even surface' enough to land. 
If you wanted to roll your own solution then set up a loop to monitor the drone after a return-to-home or landing command is sent. Then if the drone does not land, send a notice to the user to manually land the drone.

Comment: Thanks, right now I created my own solution for this scenario now. But they need to fix this issue sooner, otherwise it will confusing for user why flat area from where the drone took off is not safe enough for landing.